# Large File Transfer between Java Servers over HTTPS

Tags: java, spring, stream

I have a central server, to which many distributed servers need to transmit data in the form of somewhat large files, 500MB - 10GB+.  The servers are not on the same physical network and can't be connected to one another via a VPN.  While we're trying to get other ports opened, currently we can only talk over 443, HTTPS, which is great for our REST services but terrible for file transfer between servers.

I know this isn't as specific a question as one would like for Stackoverflow, but I would like to know: what methods might work better than the ones I've tried?

Server A -> generate file -> transfer over https -> DMZ -> proxy pass -> receive at Server B

Both servers use Java 1.8, Tomcat, and Spring 4.1.4.RELEASE.  The DMZ is just Apache and pretty much out of our control.

Things I've tried...

1. Make RPC calls to a service using Spring's HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean (this works fine for smaller sites, but the larger sites often drop connections while transferring data)
2. Multipart form post using Apache HttpPost (this also works, but we have to configure file limits in apache/tomcat, plus its connection is unreliable as well)
3. Using a library called RMIIO, which basically simulates RMI over HTTP if configured properly.  This seemed promising as it requests a stream from the server and writes to the stream from the remote server.  I haven't really gotten this to work over HTTPS yet, and the library was written in 2007 (with some updates up through July 2016), but it feels very dated, not highly maintained and I suspect there are better ways to do this sort of thing now-a-days (not that I can find them)
4. Looked at gRPC but realized it's just a binary protocol and I'd have to basically handle chunking the files if I wanted to get a streaming effect.
5. Read an article about Developing non-blocking REST services with Spring MVC, http://callistaenterprise.se/blogg/teknik/2014/04/22/c10k-developing-non-blocking-rest-services-with-spring-mvc/ again looked interesting if we were receiving a lot of files at the same time, but I don't see how it helps with a single file transfer.

I've looked at a lot of other things and tried a few more, but it all seems wrong.  When I read about big data and Spark streams or any of the million streaming options that I see, I feel like there should be something similar for transferring a single file from one server to another without a broker in the middle.  Maybe there are, just not over HTTPS.

It would be nice to know the progress of the transfer (on both ends) and be able to recover should there be connectivity issues or transfer errors.

But any direction or thoughts would be immensely helpful.  Thanks for your time and input.